# How to change class name of ANOTHER element (not the target) on scroll using IntersectionObserver?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my current code which does the following: When the user scrolls down past a certain point, a new class name is added to a sticky div. This functionally allows me to change the CSS of that element only when the user scrolls down to that point.

```
const el = document.querySelector(".myElement")
const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => e.target.classList.toggle("is-pinned", e.intersectionRatio < 1),
  { threshold: [1] }
);

observer.observe(el);
```

What I would ALSO like to do is change the name of ANOTHER element at this same scroll point. What would be the best way to accomplish this? One idea I have is, use MutationObserver to look for a class name change. However it seems there should be a much simpler way to be able to simply make an additional change within this same piece of code I have here. By that I mean, simply add another statement to the function that fires here to trigger the current class change.

There is a specific span element where I'd like to add a similar class name toggle, just as seen here. But for this span element.

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined hide-stuff-arrow">keyboard_double_arrow_up</span>
```

Ideally I'd be able to toggle one additional class name ("is-pinned-2"), on this particular element, at the exact same scroll point of the previously seen IntersectionObserver.

Then I'd be able to modify the CSS of this element to my liking, so its appearance changes only when the user has scrolled past a certain point.

What would be the best way to do this? Could I just add an additional statement into this existing chunk of code that just does a querySelector on the span element, then adds another class name to it? That would be the simplest way, if it's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You have just described how to solve your problem. So what is your question? The "best" way to do it? Are you having trouble implementing your solution?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to add that additional statement into my current chunk of code. My syntax is off somehow. I tried doing a semi-colon after the "threshold" part of it, then adding a test statement, but that didn't work properly

Comment: Well then, show your attempt and ask why it doesn't work.

Comment: const el = document.querySelector(".myElement")
const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => {e.target.classList.toggle("is-pinned", e.intersectionRatio < 1),
  { threshold: [1] };
alert('hello world'}
);

observer.observe(el);

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I meant, uh, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73750969/edit) the question to include it.

Comment: How did I miss your attempt at the very beginning of the question. My bad. Do you get any errors in the console? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: THAT part works fine, at the beginning. What that does is adds a new class name to the parent div container. What I am trying to do is take that existing code, and add one additional completely new statement to it that will basically look like this:

document.querySelector(".hide-stuff-arrow").classList.add("user-scrolled-down");

This will functionally add a new class name to ANOTHER element (which happens to be inside that parent element), allowing me to modify it's CSS as well, at the same instant as the other change happens.

Comment: What's wrong with that code?

Comment: That code statement itself should work fine -- my problem is I just don't understand the syntax of the IntersectionObserver chunk of code I currently have, and where to insert this new code to make it fire as an additional statement.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the arrow function's body:

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle("is-pinned", e.intersectionRatio < 1);
    document.querySelector(".hide-stuff-arrow").classList.add("user-scrolled-down", e.intersectionRatio < 1);
  },
  { threshold: [1] }
);
```

The return of the callback is meaningless to the intersection observer so this should not affect the existing behavior.

Also see: [how arrow functions differ from normal ones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions)

Comment: Something is wrong with that syntax. It fires that second statement, when it's placed there formatted like that, immediately on page load -- NOT on the scroll event. (This becomes especially clear when I test it with other events as well, like change the color of the element, display an alert, etc.)

Comment: Doesn't that mean your intersection observer is firing immediately on page load?

Comment: Here's the syntax that made it work: const el = document.querySelector(".myElement")
const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle("is-pinned", e.intersectionRatio < 1);
    document.querySelector(".hide-stuff-arrow").classList.toggle("user-scrolled-down", e.intersectionRatio < 1); 
  },
  { threshold: [1] }
);

Comment: Ah, you just needed to add the condition to the new toggle.

Comment: Yep, somehow managed to fumble my way through it with your help haha. Thanks!